# i want to save all records from database in a file (read from database a)

Tags: xml, database, record, mule, mule-studio

i did a example  [Using Mule Studio to read Data from database](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article2068-using-mule-studio-to-read-data-from-postgresqlinbound-and-write-it-to-fil.aspx)

i have not any problem or errors but i want to change this program.
this program create a lot of files and read one record and save in to in a files
and mule program create and create a lot of file until i terminate my program 
i want to save all records in a file and finish the program (not continue again).
i left my xml file

```
 <jdbc:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source" user="roor" password="1234" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/readdata" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"/>
<jdbc:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"/>
<flow name="DBC-PostgreSQL-Mule-ExperimentFlow1" doc:name="DBC-PostgreSQL-Mule-ExperimentFlow1">
    <jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="selectplayers" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="1000" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
        <jdbc:transaction action="NONE"/>
        <jdbc:query key="selectplayers" value="Select * From Players;"/>
    </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\me\Mule\sample\1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[function:dateStamp].txt"/>
</flow>
```

error after add   :

```
xception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 16 in XML document from URL [file:/E:/program/MuleStudio/.mule/apps/dbc-postgresql-mule-experiment/DBC-PostgreSQL-Mule-Experiment.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
    ... 4 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved by using collection aggregation: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-CollectionAggregator

In your case you'll have to set a correlation ID and group size that matches your select so Mule will wait for the right number of records to aggregate before writing them to a single file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different inbound endpoint to trigger the jdbc data extraction (Quartz, VM, etc). This way all records are stored in a single mule message and finally in a single file.

```
<flow name="DBC-PostgreSQL-Mule-ExperimentFlow1" doc:name="DBC-PostgreSQL-Mule-ExperimentFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="start" repeatInterval="60000">
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="selectplayers" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
        <jdbc:transaction action="NONE"/>
        <jdbc:query key="selectplayers" value="Select * From Players;"/>
    </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\me\Mule\sample\1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[function:dateStamp].txt"/>
</flow>
```

Regards

Comment: thanks for replye i addes  <vm:inbound-endpoint address="vm://in"/> in flow  without any configureation but i have errors ,  i left my console im question please explain more thanks a lot

Comment: See my answer, you also have to change your `jdbc:inbound-endpoint` to `jdbc:outbound-endpoint` and add `exchange-pattern="request-response"`

Comment: i copied your code in my program but i have error:Attribute 'pollingFrequency' is not allowed to appear in element 'jdbc:outbound-endpoint'. i cleaned pollingFrequency attribute  i had not error but my program did not create any file , pollingFrequency is for <jdbc:connector

Comment: Try using a logger to find out if your query is returning results. I corrected the `pollingFrequency` wich is not necessary in this case.

Comment: i didn't successful i left picture in my question for u i think i must configure vm  --> or i must change vm://in can u help me more i u can send one email for me maryam.masoudy@gmail.com if u want not send email please explain more here thanks Daniel

Comment: VM endpoint doesn't generate messages to start the flow. I updated my answer changing VM for Quartz

Comment: excuse me masoudy.maryam@gmail.com

Comment: i could successful finally :) i am very very beginner this resolve was very simple